# Static vs member field revisited, need advice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need an advice on piece of functionality that I am ought to implement. The scenario is that we haven an HttpHandler which servers to intercept file uploads. In the handler, I need to persist a large dictionary of strings inside the memory. The dictionary might be as large as 100 entries. I am wondering whether it is safe to store that in a static variable, so that it is not initialized every time instance of the handler is created (there will be a lot of instance for sure). In general, what is the approach in such scenarios. Is it a generally better idea to use static fields, to persist data that will not be changed?

Comment: You mean static property vs static field?

Comment: May I ask, what you have in this dictionary and where is this data coming from? Seeing that file uploads are typically very slow there is no need for high performance here.

Comment: The dictionary would contain mime types mapped to extensions. I need to manually set the content type of the uploaded file, because uploads from Silverlight/Flash always come with content type of Application/octet-stream, which is unacceptable.

Comment: So you really don't need to cache the whole list. Simple get the one you need (I'm guessing, based on the file extension). You could use the memory for other cases where it's more important while in this case you could simply get the data from your database.

Comment: @Genady, keep in mind also, that technically there could be multiple copies of your dictionary in memory (which is a waste in this scenario). The reason (for the multiple copies) is that in the Process Model of your app pool, if you set the MaxWorkerProcesses to more than 1 (which you typically would do in this case, because file uploads take time and you want additional processes available to process other kinds of requests), then each worker process will be in a different app domain and so multiple copies of your static dictionary will exist on the server machine using more memory

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Indeed, it makes sense. My original thought was to put the mime-type/extension pairs inside an XML document and fetch them on demand. However, this might rise other, IO issues.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues reading the file from multiple threads/processes if you use FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read as the parameters when you create the instance of FileStream. You'll be surprised by the performance of this (using a file for this purpose) even though performance is not much of a consideration in this case. A database table will work just as well. Are you dealing with media files (images, music, videos) only or other types of files as well? The reason I ask is that you may need a more robust way of getting the mime-type in media file cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100 items in a dictionary isn't really very big - in fact, that is barely getting into the size where hashing is faster than linear search. If it will **never** change once initialized, then static may work - personally I try to have some other abstraction between `static` and instance - for example a "context" or "configuration" class that I can pass into all the instances that need it. Then I can have multiple parallel configurations (if I need), but all the **related** instances can share a context/configuration - so no duplication.

Comment: wait, didn't you mean "isn't really very big"?

Comment: The items will never change, they are basically content-type/extension pairs, which are predefined and are unlikely to change in the future. Thank you for the feedback, I will stick to the static field approach.

Comment: I think you may want to revise the first sentence, it doesn't make sense; "100 items in a dictionary is really very big"

Comment: @massif @DoctaJonez - yes, sorry; inversion #fail

Answer (score 1):

IMHO a static field is just fine. You could initialize it at first use. Just make sure, you are using thread synchronisation.
You could also use a singleton, but I think, that would be a little bit overkill...

Answer (score 1):

It's a good solution. Initialize the dictionary at the startup of your application(e.g. Global.asax) and it's ready for being read from since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `HttpHandler.IsReusable` and return `false` in order not to have your handler recreated every time. You can then store the dictionary in local member.

Otherwise you need to use static variable.

Your dictionary doesn't seem to be big - 100 entries is peanuts. Unless each string is a few Megs long.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that multiple instances will be created (eventually) and each will need to initialize their own copy. Not only that, there will be multiple copies in memory now since te handlers are reusable.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary is going to be same for all the instances use static field otherwise use property field

If your data will not be changed then use Readonly variable

Comment: How will readonly help here? In this case readonly simply means the dictionary itself can't be set to another instance. It does not prevent items in the existing dictionary from being modified. And in this case if they are modified and the field is static, the OP will need to synchronize reading/adding from/to the ditionary.